# Navigating and showing snackbar at the same time causes it to disappear too fast

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

It seems like when I navigate + show a snackbar from a destination, it flickers for a second and then disappears, instead, if I'm inside a screen without navigating the snackbar shows correctly.

This is my code:

From composable A I send an event to the snackbar host to show a message like so:

```
@Composable
fun ComposableA(showSnackBarMessage: (message: String, isError: Boolean) -> Unit) {
 ... 
  if((uiState.value as ProfileState.ProfileUiState).profileScreenUiState.accountDeleted) {
                viewModel.resetVariables()
                onNavigateBackToLogin.invoke()
                showSnackBarMessage("Account deleted", false)
            }
}
```

Now in MainActivity I receive this event and show a snackbar (meanwhile the navigation happens)

```
override fun onCreate(...) {

setContent {
    val scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    var snackBarMessage: String? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
    var isError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var localState by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    MyTheme {

        if (localState) {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) {
                if (snackBarMessage != null) {
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        message = snackBarMessage ?: ""
                    )
                    snackBarMessage = null
                }
            }
            localState = false
        }

        Scaffold(
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            snackbarHost = {
                SnackbarHost(hostState = it) { data ->
                    Snackbar(
                        snackbarData = data,
                        backgroundColor = if (!isError) GreenProfit else Color.Red,
                        contentColor = Color.White
                    )
                }
            },
            backgroundColor = Color.Black
        ) {
                NavigationGraph(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding()),
                    navController = navController,
                    showSnackBarMessage = { message, showError ->
                        isError = showError
                        snackBarMessage = message
                        localState = true
                    }
                )
            }
```

I'm using a localState to trigger the snackbar whenever an event occurs, then I check if the snackBarMessage is not null (since we could send the same message twice and I need it to show again, that's why inside the LaunchedEffect I validate it), then I set the message as null and the state as false so it will not re-launch or re-compose.

Now, the issue is that navigating from my profile screen to the login screen will trigger maybe 3 or more compositions since the frames are being rendered, and seems like it goes through really quick and I cannot see the default duration of the snackbar, instead this happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in how you manage the screen states, I had the same issue and I noticed that I was changing the UIState after showing the SnackBar causing the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you add a few more details here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).